# Persistence of irrationally indifferent periodic points

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

I am trying to see when an irrationally indifferent periodic point persists for a holomorphic family of rational maps on the Riemann sphere. This is a question I am currently pondering after reading Mañé, Sad and Sullivan's 1983 paper "On the dynamics of rational maps", where one of their main results essentially says that one can always approximate any rational map of degree $d$ by rational maps of same degree with the property that they only have hyperbolic or persistently non-hyperbolic periodic points. In particular, the paper says that if some map in the family has a persistently non-hyperbolic periodic point, then every map in the family has a non-hyperbolic periodic point. I am interested in being able to strengthen this result specifically for irrationally indifferent periodic points, and hence when Siegel discs persist, if they do at all.

I haven't managed to find any further results on this matter and this is the first time that I have asked a question on this site, so please forgive me if I've overlooked something utterly obvious or the question is not of appropriate level.

**Edit:** As said in the comments, I should try and formulate a clear question. Suppose a rational map $f_\lambda$ in a holomorphic family $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha \in X}$ (where $X$ is a complex manifold) has a cycle of Siegel discs and hence a Siegel periodic point $z_0$. When does $z_0$ persist as an irrationally indifferent periodic point? Even stronger, when does $z_0$ persist as Siegel periodic point?

Comment: Because the set of irrational numbers is completely disconnected,  the only way you can have a persistent irrationally indifferent point is to have a constant multiplier. By analyticity, this property must be shared by every member of the family (observe in particular that the multiplier being constant prevents the merging of fixedpoints, hence there is no "parbabolic implosion" in the family). Is that the kind of arguments you're looking for? I don't know offhand how to deal with the local linearizability, though.

Comment: (By the way, you should formulate a question.)

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: I've clarified my post to have a proper question that can be answered, hopefully this helps!